# SSL Cert on internal private network

Tags: ssl, networking

I have a Server which is on both the internet and a private network.

I am trying to set up TLS on an internal private network as requested by my manager.

The service is available to both internet and private internal network clients.

External clients use the internet with their Client certificates - this works great.

Internal clients get an Cert error as they are accessing the service using the IP address of the server on the internal network.

I've tried 'trick' the client machines by translating the domain name in the Server cert to the IP address of the server - but we still get the server cert Error.

As far as I am aware I cant get a cert issued for the server as it's not a verifiable domain name ( in fact its an IP address ). We do not have any DNS on the private network.

Any idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you set up *split DNS* to resolve the server's name to the private IP instead of the public IP - your local DNS server just resolves the name by a local entry instead of passing the request to an upstream server. That way, both internal and external users resolve the name to the address they need and both groups are happy.

If you do need to use IP addresses you have to include both of them as *alternate names* in the certificate.